# API Management restricting IP ranges via Service Tag

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-api-management

I've currently got an App Service in Azure that I can add an access restriction to, that only allows requests from an IP address that is defined within a service tag by Microsoft (in this case AzureActiveDirectory):

[image: Add rule UI from Azure portal showing the Service Tag source option]

I am adding the API from this App Service into API Management, so no direct requests are made to the App Service, and everything runs through API Management. I have seen in the [access restriction documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-access-restriction-policies#RestrictCallerIPs) for API Management there is the ip-filter policy I can use, which also allows IP ranges to be defined. Is this the only way I can restrict the traffic going through my API Management Service, or is there a way to define service tags like on App Service?

A follow up question to this: I have got this list of IP ranges for all the service tags (found [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=56519&WT.mc_id=rss_alldownloads_all) from Microsoft docs). Can I define IP addresses such as 0.0.0.0/32 (using zeros just as an example of the format) in the ip-filter? And if so, would Microsoft regularly update their IP ranges for a Service Tag?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I Know,
You cannot alter the IP ranges in the Service Tag data provided for each Azure Resource,
[image]

but you can specify the IP Range in CIDR notation also multiple with comma separated Ranges by Selecting the Source/Destination as IP Addresses:
[image]

You can add the Multiple IP Address ranges by adding a new rule to every IP CIDR Range and can alter or deny as per need and also can specify the priority for all rules.